# Can I use a function instead of color name in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-native-stylesheet

I created a counter app using redux I want to change the color when the value is 0 and again change when the value is 1. I created a function for this, when I use console.log its shows the right color name but it does not show when I call a function in the background color name it shows undefined. (I did't want to use ternary operator for this)

```
class counterApp extends Component {

    state={
        maincolor: '',
    }

    
    fun(){
        
        if (this.props.counter == 0) {
            this.state.maincolor = dark.bg
            
        }
        else {
            this.state.maincolor = light.bg
            
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ 
                  justifyContent: 'center', 
                  alignItems: 'center', top: '45%', 
                  backgroundColor: this.fun()
                
             }}>
```

Comment: Try adding return in the function? `fun () { if (this.props.counter == 0) { return dark.bg } }`

Comment: How is this relevant to the `python` tag?

Comment: Have you any problem with this?

Answer (score 1):

Your function returns nothing! so that's why you get `undefined`
You have to return color in `fun()`

```
fun(){
    if (this.props.counter == 0) return dark.bg;
    return light.bg;
}
```

Also you can not set state values directly ([React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)), instead you should do it with `setState`
In this example you can do it like this

```
fun() {
    if (this.props.counter == 0) this.setState({ maincolor: dark.bg });
    else this.setState({ maincolor: light.bg});
}
```

Now, call `fun()` somewhere (for example in `componentDidMount` or `constructor`),
and use it in render

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', top: '45%', 
            backgroundColor: this.state.maincolor
            
         }}>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Its works but when I refresh, it updates otherwise it takes only the first value. Is it possible to update value according to value change?